# Data Validation VBA works when running Excel 2016 on Win7 but does not on Windows 10

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running a macro that pulls data from a data base and then populates a simple menu using this data.  This function works perfectly when running Excel 2016 on Win7 but when users on Win10 run the macro (also using Excel 2016) an error is thrown on Selection.Validation .add : "1004 object-defined or application-defined error".  Any thoughts about what would cause this error in Win10 vs. Win7 and how I can correct it to work with both operating systems?

I'd prefer not to make a separate tab to hold the validation data, if possible.

```
Function populateMenu()


    Dim datafield As ADODB.Field
    Dim datapull As Object
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim sqlQuery As String
    Dim lobNames(200) As Variant
    Dim elementCounter As Integer

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set datapull = New ADODB.Recordset
    conn.ConnectionString = CONNECTSTRING
    conn.Open


    sqlQuery = getLOBNames
    datapull.Open sqlQuery, conn

     elementCounter = 0
     Do While Not datapull.EOF
        For Each datafield In datapull.Fields
           lobNames(elementCounter) = datafield.Value
           elementCounter = elementCounter + 1
        Next datafield
        datapull.MoveNext
    Loop

    datapull.Close
    conn.Close
    Set datapull = Nothing
    Set Connection = Nothing

    'LOB Pull Down
    Worksheets("Data").Select
    Range("B3").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(lobNames, ",")
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = "SELECT LOB"
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: What's the output from `Join(lobNames, ",")` when it fails?  Is it what you expect?

Comment: Join(lobNames, ",") returns a comma delimited string containing names intended to appear in the pull down menu. This produces the expected output when running on either OS.

Comment: Maybe try `With Worksheets("Data").Range("B3").Validation` instead of making a selection.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion (it's definitely cleaner than the original). It still executes with the same outcome.

Comment: It appears that there is a 256 character limit when executing a delimited list in Excel 2016.  This limit is not recognized when running Win7 but when running win10 it seems to be strictly enforced.  Despite not wanting to store the data in another tab there appears to be no way around it. I appreciate you taking the time to look at it Tim!  - source: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/what-is-limit-of-the-number-of-entries-in-excel/9ce4a909-8b03-428f-94a4-1b13433aa399